# Change date from one format to another using NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, ios5

How can I convert NSDateFormatted string `Apr 18, 2014 10:34:19 AM` to `2014-04-18T17:34:19`? I have tried the below but it returns a `nil` `NSDate` pointer.
Can anyone here please help me out.
Thanks.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Apr 18, 2014 10:34:19 AM"];  // Error nil
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

Comment: Read it with a format matching how it is now, then format it with a format matching how you'd like it to be.  Remember, an NSDate has no defined format -- how it displays in NSLog is just the debug format.

Comment: (Clearly the above format does not match the date you're trying to read.)

Comment: Bookmark the [date format patterns page](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), as you will want to refer to it often.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use 2 date formatters, one for parsing the other for displaying:

```
NSDateFormatter *parsingFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[parsingFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [parsingFormatter dateFromString:@"Apr 18, 2014 10:34:19 AM"];
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);

NSDateFormatter *displayingFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[displayingFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"];
NSString *display = [displayingFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"display: %@", display); // 2014-04-18T17:34:19
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Rich. The key here is using the NSDate from parsingFormatter in displayingFormatter stringFromDate.

Comment: FYI - there is no need to put quotes around the punctuation in the format string, just around the `T`.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without first converting to an NSDate object?

Comment: @JohnnyRockex nope!

Comment: I was asking re performance;  if one analysed the string first using nsrange etc. probably take a performance hit that's the same as equating to nsdate, so probably not worth it anyway.

Comment: @JohnnyRockex the best thing you can probably do is `dispatch_once` both date formatters if you're doing this lots of times.

Comment: Yep, keep the formatters active, it just seems we wouldn't need the full whack of nsdate for scenarios where we're just manipulating strings.