# Convert date string(2016-04-27T08:06:07.531Z) to specific date format dd.MM.YYYY

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

I have date string in the format 2016-04-27T08:06:07.531Z and want to convert into 2016.04.27. I have tried following code

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-04-27T08:06:07.531Z";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.Z"];

NSDate *dateReceived = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YYYY"];

NSString *dateReq = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateReceived];

NSLog(@"Date Req:%@",dateReq);
```

I am getting null in console for NSLog. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use 2 date formatters. Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140448/change-date-from-one-format-to-another-using-nsdateformatter

Comment: @nanjunda: You shouldn't need to use two `NSDateFormatter`. One should be enough. It's just that the author didn't gave enough informations about debugging: Is `dateReceived` nil? Because that would mean that the error is there. In other words, it's lacking information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-04-27T08:06:07.531Z";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];

NSDate *dateReceived = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
                             // 2016.04.27
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy.MM.dd"];

NSString *dateReq = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateReceived];

NSLog(@"Date Req:%@",dateReq);
```

[image]

Comment: For the first formatter, you should make sure to specify `locale` per [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: Its  worked for     [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zzzZ"];

Comment: @PavanMore No, it's not `.zzz`. It's `.SSS`.

Answer (score 1):

Plz just change your date formatter's date format

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
```

instead of

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.Z"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will help you --

```
NSString *date = @"2011-02-27T08:06:07.531Z";
NSDateFormatter *dFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];

NSDate *dReceive = [dFormat dateFromString:dateString];

[dFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.Z"];

NSString *dateReq = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dReceive];
```

just change date format

```
[dFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.Z"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date format as: `[dFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.Z"];`